# Change legend symbol in Column Chart in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I want to change the legend Symbol in column chart and make a legend Symbol like spline. I've seen the document => legend.

As I've seen I can change the legend width and some other features like CSS designing but how can I change the symbol?

[image]

change to

[image]

Please help...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe the Highchart's API offers the ability to customize the legend symbol with a bar chart.  You can, however, modify the symbol after the chart is drawn.

```js
   chart: {
        type: 'column',
        events: {
            load: function(event) {
                // modify the legend symbol from a rect to a line
                $('.highcharts-legend-item rect').attr('height', '2').attr('y', '10');
            }
        }   
    },
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/L5GLA/).

[image]

Comment: How is it possible in highstock?

Comment: I've tested it for highstock. Since I have other types of charts I think managing the legend in the chart is not ok, so the customization should take part in the plotOptions property: column but I have not found a solution to change the height attr.

Comment: This solution works only for SVG based browsers (not IE 6/7/8 and Android 2.x).

Answer (score 2):

Since Highcharts 3.0 you can use `linkedTo` option. [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.linkedTo) with the demo.

Comment: In my idea this solutions is not really good,In order to have a legend symbol like line series, we are making an empty series and link another chart type to it...

Comment: Yes, but this solution works in all supported by Highcharts browsers.

Comment: So, it's recommanded to add this property for add browsers.Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

**Remove Legend** symbol

```js
 chart: {
        type: 'column',
        events: {
            load: function(event) {
                // modify the legend symbol from a rect to a line
                $('.highcharts-legend-item rect').attr('r', '0');
            }
        }   
    },
```